# SSRS 2008 Report Builder 3.0: Optional User Entered Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

My program allows the user to enter in the parameters `Start Date`, `End Date`, and `Shift`.

I am going to add another one that is called `VCN`. This allowed the user to enter in a specific part number and the program will search for the data related to it.

However, when I do this I want to be able to shut off the other 3 parameters. This means the user can either enter in the first 3 parameters OR a `VCN` number. When a user enters a `VCN` number I do not want the search to be bound by my other 3 parameters.

Comment: Nice question about disabling a parameter based on another. However it seems you need 2 reports. One for the current and another that only has the `VCN` parameter only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it would seem you are better off with two reports and this would be my preference.

I haven't found a way to disable a parameter based on another but I would suggest to use the `VCN` parameter as an override. In this I would:

1. Set `VCN` up as optional and allow nulls.
2. Have `VCN` have a default and set to `null` and allow the report to run as normal.
3. If the user enters anything in the `VCN` then use this and ignore anything in the other parameters.
4. Then use if `VCN` is null then disble the other queries or do as you need.